# Laravel 4 many to many relationships

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

Lets say we have to following tables:

Games

GameQuestions

Questions

Answers

Now in order to get get questions related to single game I got the following controller snippet:

```
if ($code) {
            $gamedata = Game::with('questions')
                ->where('secretcode', $code)
                ->get();
        }else{
            $gamedata = Game::with('questions')->get();

        }
```

Heres my Game model:

```
class Game extends Eloquent {


    /*table definition*/
    protected $table = 'games';


        public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Question', 'gamequestions', 'game_id', 'question_id');
    }

}
```

And Question model:

class Question extends Eloquent {

```
/*table definition*/
protected $table = 'questions';

//questions relation
public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany('Answer', 'question_id', 'id');
}
```

}

Now getting the games and their related questions seem to work with this code.  **However I would also want to include the answers.**  How would this code need to be amended in order to accomodate for yet another foreign key relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can nest the relationships;

```
if ($code) {
            $gamedata = Game::with('questions.answers')
                ->where('secretcode', $code)
                ->get();
        }else{
            $gamedata = Game::with('questions.answers')->get();

        }
```

See the docs http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading - search for nested relationships

> $books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
>
> In the example above, the author relationship will be eager loaded, and the author's contacts relation will also be loaded.